# parsing json to python

Tags: json, python-2.7, scikit-learn

i have json data like this:

```
{"random_forest":{
 "method":"RandomForestClassifier()", 
  "base_estimator":[{"model":"ET = ExtraTreesClassifier()"},
   {"model":"DecisionTreeClassifier()"}],
            "params":{
            "max_features":["auto","sqrt","log2"],
            "n_jobs":"-1",
            "oob_score":"True",
            "class_weight":["auto","balanced","balanced_subsample"],
            "criterion":["gini","entropy"]}},
            "masks":{"id":"valore"},
            "om_points":"value",
            "parameters":{"id":"valore"}
            }
```

i successfully get the method and params data for running in scikit-learn with this:

```
json_data = json.loads(open('hp_values.json').read())
method = json_data['random_forest']['method'].encode('utf-8')
params = json.dumps(json_data['random_forest']['params'])
```

but i get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\all in one place\skripsi\project\siijah\skripsi\cobaJamu2.py",
  line 470, in <module>
  main()
  File "E:\all in one place\skripsi\project\siijah\skripsi\cobaJamu2.py",                              line 422, in main
    meta_clf = tune_hyperparams_RF(X_train, y_train)
  File "E:\all in one place\skripsi\project\siijah\skripsi\cobaJamu2.py", line 122, in tune_hyperparams_RF
    return tune(method, params, X_train, y_train)
  File "E:\all in one place\skripsi\project\siijah\skripsi\cobaJamu2.py", line 63, in tune
    clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(method, param_grid=params, n_jobs = 4, cv=kf_cv, scoring='accuracy')
  File "C:\Users\deni suswanto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 787, in __init__
    _check_param_grid(param_grid)
  File "C:\Users\deni suswanto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 322, in _check_param_grid
    for v in p.values():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

then, i try to print output of **json_data['random_forest']['params']**, and here's the output:

```
{u'max_features': [u'auto', u'sqrt', u'log2'], u'oob_score': u'True', u'n_jobs': u'-1', u'criterion': [u'gini', u'entropy'], u'class_weight': [u'auto', u'balanced', u'balanced_subsample']}
```

and i print output of **json_data['random_forest']['method']**, output:

```
u'RandomForestClassifier()'
```

but, when i try print without parsing from json, i print the method and get output:

```
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
        max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
        oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
        warm_start=False)
```

and the params:

```
{'oob_score': [True, False], 'n_jobs': [-1], 'n_estimators': [300, 1000, 400], 'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'], 'class_weight': ['auto', 'balanced', 'balanced_subsample']}
```

so i try to dump it, but it generate to string.
i have try many different ways. but it's still doesn't work.
does anyone have the answer?

Comment: Try `params = json_data['random_forest']['params']` instead

Comment: i have try it but it get another error like this :
    raise ValueError("Parameter values should be a list.")
    ValueError: Parameter values should be a list.

Comment: Please, post the whole traceback. `json.dumps` is definitely wrong here - it creates a json string from a dictionary.

Comment: well yeah, i just realize that
but i use python 2.7 that if i don't dump it, it get 'u' character.

Comment: Anyway, post the new traceback. And also output of `print json_data['random_forest']['params']`.

Comment: ok,
here's the output of json_data['random_forest']['params'] :


    `{u'max_features': [u'auto', u'sqrt', u'log2'], u'oob_score': u'True',    u'n_jobs': u'-1', u'criterion': [u'gini', u'entropy'], u'class_weight': [u'auto', u'balanced', u'balanced_subsample']}`

Comment: i got the answer is the json is totally wrong,
i validate it in [JsonLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).
thanks for all answers, appreciated it :)

Comment: You could post your comment as an answer and accept it.